# How to mock Material-UI withWidth HOC

Tags: reactjs, mocking, material-ui, jestjs

Suppose I have a component which is wrapped in Material-UI's withWidth HOC. How do you mock withWidth's isWidthUp function using jest to return a predetermined bool?

**SUT**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import withWidth, { isWidthUp } from '@material-ui/core/withWidth';

class ComponentWithWidth extends Component {

    render() {
        const { width } = this.props;

        return isWidthUp('md', width)
            ? <p>above md</p>
            : <p>below md</p>;
    }
}

export default withWidth()(ComponentWithWidth);
```

**What I have tried**

**Attempt 1**

```
import React from 'react';
import { configure, mount } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import ComponentWithWidth from '../ComponentWithWidth';
import { isWidthUp } from '@material-ui/core/withWidth';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

jest.mock('@material-ui/core/withWidth');

describe('ComponentWithWidth', () => {

    it('Should render', () => {

        isWidthUp = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true);

        const el = mount(<ComponentWithWidth />);
    });
});
```

**Problem**

```
TypeError: (0 , _withWidth.default)(...) is not a function
```

**Attempt 2**

```
import React from 'react';
import { configure, mount } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import ComponentWithWidth from '../ComponentWithWidth';
import withWidth from '@material-ui/core/withWidth';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('ComponentWithWidth', () => {

    it('Should render', () => {

        withWidth.isWidthUp = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(false);

        const el = mount(<ComponentWithWidth />);
    });
});
```

**Problem**

The component disregards the widthWidth.isWidthUp mock return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with esmodules mocking but I do think that you should not test it this way (testing implementation details that is).

You could simply pass the `width` prop in the mount which is basically mocking. See `demo.test.js`: https://codesandbox.io/s/m9o783rox